# Position radalert next to button that opens it

Tags: asp.net, telerik, radwindow

I have a master page with RadWindowManager in it.

In a child page, there are multiple buttons. On clicking each a radalert message pops up, but it shows in center of page and I would like to show it to immediate right of the button.

**How would I make sure that radalert popup shows to immediate right of the clicked button?** Bottom of radalert should align with bottom of clicked button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use JavaScript to move the dialog when you open it. Something like:

```
<asp:Button ID="Button1" Text="open RA" OnClientClick="openRA(this); return false;" runat="server" />
<script type="text/javascript">
    function openRA(btn)
    {
        var oAlert = radalert("message");
        var btnPos = $telerik.getBounds(btn);
        oAlert.moveTo(btnPos.x + btnPos.width, btnPos.y - oAlert.getWindowBounds().height);
    }
</script>
```